# in ASP.NET MVC3 How to bind and provide an action to the listbox with the single selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net mvc3 razor view how to bind the list of strings in the listbox with the single selection.
I am trying to bind list of Names (List) with the ListBox.

```
**Model**

Class StudentInfo
{
public string id{get,set};
public string names{get,set};
}

**In Conrtoller**
[HTTPGet]
public ActionResult Student()
{

List<StudentInfo> liststudent=new LIst<StudentInfo>{
new StudentInfo{id="v11",names="AB"},
new StudentInfo{id="v12",names="SA"},
return View(liststudent)
}

}
[HTTPPost]
public ActionResult Student(string name)
{

return View()
}

}

**In View**

    <div class="alignright">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.ListBox("MyList",new SelectList(???));
    }
    </div>
```

**The problem I am encountering are:
1. How to display the names of the student in the listbox. 
2. How to provide an action with the selection.**

Comment: A simple google search is enough to get the answers. You didn't really try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**your controller**

```
public ActionResult Student()
{
    List<StudentInfo> liststudent=new LIst<StudentInfo>{
                        new StudentInfo{id="v11",names="AB"},
                        new StudentInfo{id="v12",names="SA"}}
    return View(liststudent);
}
```

**your view**

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.StudentInfo>

<div class="alignright">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.ListBox("MyList",new SelectList(model, "id", "names"));
    }
    </div>
```